# PSTricks: Lines not shown on the right side

Tags: pstricks

I want to make a rather big flowchart using PSTricks. Worked fine in the beginning, but as it got larger it didn't show the frames and line on the right side of the paper anymore.

I'm compiling with XeLaTex.

Here's a minimal example where the problem occurs as well:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}
\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}&\psdiabox[]{text}\\
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Any suggestions what the error is here and how to avoid it?

Comment: If one compiles is with latex and converts the ps to pdf, the issue does not arise. So most likely the bug is related to XeLaTeX, and a simple workaround is to compile with latex instead.

Answer (score 1):

With `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` the class `standalone` cannot detect the correct width of the image. Use `xelatex` and

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}
    \psdiabox[]{text} & \psdiabox[]{text} & \psdiabox[]{text} & \psdiabox[]{text} & %
                        \psdiabox[]{text} & \psdiabox[]{text} &\psdiabox[]{text} & %
                        \psdiabox[]{text} & \psdiabox[]{text}\\
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

and it should work:

[image]